# ¿Cómo contar elementos repetidos en un array?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Tengo la siguiente duda, tengo un `array` de enteros con n elementos, lo que necesito es que me retorne en un `array` bidimensional el elemento y el número de veces que se repite, a continuación un ejemplo:

- n = 9
- `array` = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2}
- El resultado sería: arrayBidimensional = { {1,4}, {2,3}, {3,1}, {5,1} }

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 int contador = 0;
 int[] ar = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2};
 for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0 ; j < ar.length; j++)
         if(ar[i] == ar[j])
             contador++;
     System.out.print(contador + ",");
     contador = 0;
 }
```

Y como resultado obtengo lo siguiente:

```
4,3,3,4,4,1,1,4,3,
```

Los cuales son las veces que se repite cada elemento, solamente que en el código anterior se presentan repetidas. De este punto realmente no se como proceder.

**Nota: Se que con un ArrayList se podría resolver mucho mejor, pero por esta vez quisiera que solo sea con arrays.**

Por favor espero puedan ayudarme con esta inquietud.

Comment: Básicamente tendrías que aplicar algoritmos de ordenamiento y búsqueda a un arreglo, es un buen ejercicio; a menos que definas alguna(s) restricción(es) como valor mínimo/máximo de elemento, número máximo de elementos distintos, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno con la ayuda de la respuesta de [@Mauro Villalba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/269976/4413), la usé para el método `encontrarElementosRepetidos(int[] array)` y para eliminar los elementos repetidos use lo siguiente [eliminarDuplicados(int[] array)](https://howtodoinjava.com/array/array-remove-duplicate-elements/):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ar = { 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2 };

    // ARRAY ORDENADO
    Arrays.sort(ar);

    // ARRAY DE NUMERO DE ELEMENTOS
    int[] arNumElementos = encontrarElementosRepetidos(ar);

    // ARRAY DE NUMEROS NO REPETIDOS ORDENADOS
    int[] arNoDuplicates = eliminarDuplicados(ar);

    // CONTAR NUMERO DE ELEMENTOS PARA EL ARRAY BIDIMENSIONAL
    int contadorOnly = 0;
    for (int elemento : arNoDuplicates) {
        if (elemento != 0)
            contadorOnly++;
    }

    // ARRAY BIDIMENSIONAL CON EL ELEMENTO Y NUMERO DE ELEMENTOS
    int[][] arRepetidos = new int[contadorOnly][2];

    for (int x = 0; x < arRepetidos.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < arRepetidos[x].length; y++)
            if (y == 0)
                arRepetidos[x][y] = arNoDuplicates[x];
            else
                arRepetidos[x][y] = arNumElementos[x];

    // IMPRIMIR ARRAY BIDIMENSIONAL
    for (int x = 0; x < arRepetidos.length; x++) {
        System.out.print("{ ");
        for (int y = 0; y < arRepetidos[x].length; y++)
            System.out.print("" + arRepetidos[x][y] + " ");
        System.out.print("},");
    }

};

private static int[] eliminarDuplicados(int[] arOriginal) {
    int[] tempArray = new int[arOriginal.length];

    int indexJ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arOriginal.length - 1; i++) {
        int elemento = arOriginal[i];
        if (elemento != arOriginal[i + 1]) {
            tempArray[indexJ++] = elemento;
        }
    }

    tempArray[indexJ++] = arOriginal[arOriginal.length - 1];

    return tempArray;
}

private static int[] encontrarElementosRepetidos(int[] arOriginal) {
    // ARRAY ORDENADO
    Arrays.sort(arOriginal);

    // ARRAY DE NUMERO DE ELEMENTOS
    int[] arNumElementos = new int[arOriginal.length];
    int contador = 0;
    int aux = arOriginal[0];
    int iterador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arOriginal.length; i++) {
        if (aux == arOriginal[i]) {
            contador++;
        } else {
            arNumElementos[iterador] = contador;
            contador = 1;
            aux = arOriginal[i];
            iterador++;
        }

    }
    arNumElementos[iterador] = contador;
    return arNumElementos;
}
```

En este caso tengo el siguiente resultado y cumple con lo solicitado:

```
{ 1 4 },{ 2 3 },{ 3 1 },{ 5 1 },
```

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Answer (score 4):

Espero te sirva

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sorting {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int[] ar = {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5,1, 2};
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        int contador=0;
        int aux=ar[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if(aux == ar[i]){
                contador++;
            } else {
                System.out.print(contador + ",");
                contador=1;
                aux=ar[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(contador );
    }
}
```

Comment: Primero que nada bienvenido Mauri!. Ambas soluciones (la tuya y la de Gastón) son válidas pero rescato la tuya por tratarse de la manera mas "artesanal" de resolver el problema. Creo que para quien empieza en java esta sería la forma con la cual va a entender realmente como se soluciona el problema planteado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación, esto me ayuda mucho lo que ahora faltaría es presentarlo en el array bidimensional, para que cada elemento tenga el número de veces que se repite.

Answer (score 3):

La mejor forma es usar un `Set`, este no permite elementos duplicados

```
List aLista = Arrays.asList(ar);
Set<Integer> miSet = new HashSet<Integer>(aLista);
for(int s: miSet){

 System.out.println(s + " " +Collections.frequency(aLista,s));

}
```

Podes leer sobre [Collections.frequency()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-collections-frequency-java/) , este devuelve un entero

Y podes leer sobre [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) , que no permite ingresar dos valores iguales

> Mas formalmente, un set no contiene un par de elementos e1 y e2 tal que 
>   e1.equals(e2)

Comment: Mas que valido! buen aporte, desconocía el método frequency.

Comment: Gracias Franco, si, un Set o HashSet al no admitir elementos duplicados , no te va a permitir por ejemplo hacer tuSet.add(1) y volver a hacer el mismo add al mismo numero, ya que como dice la doc, no admiten elementos duplicados, el Collections.frequency() es excelente por que al no duplicarse ningun elemento en la lista solo compara la igualdad entre los elementos del array, un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Si no necesitas tener memoria constante, yo siempre opto por usar un [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), que permite guardar pares clave-valor donde las claves no se pueden repetir. De esta manera sólo tienes que recorrer tu array una sola vez:

```java
int[] casoDePrueba = { 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8 };

Map<Integer, Integer> ocurrencias = new HashMap<>();

for (int i : casoDePrueba) {
    ocurrencias.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
}

ocurrencias.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println("(" + a + ", " + b + ")"));
```

Donde [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) es un método que busca si la clave existe en tu `Map`, si no existe la crea con el valor que le has pasado (1), y si existe le aplica al valor que ya tiene un mapeo con el valor que le pases (en este caso sumamos el 1 al valor que estuviera asociado anteriormente).

Si es absolutamente necesario que tengas un array, siempre puedes convertirlo después, aquí te dejo un método que convierte un `Map<Integer, Integer` a un array de de dos dimensiones con enteros:

```java
public static int[][] convertMapTo2dArray(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    int[][] target = new int[map.size()][2];
    int index = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        target[index][0] = entry.getKey();
        target[index][1] = entry.getValue();
        index++;
    }
    return target;
}
```